# Is there a batch-file, command line, or powershell, that will assign ownership of a file to whomever you want?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command

Repeating the title:
Is there a batch-file, command line, or powershell, that will assign ownership of a file to whomever you want?
I have been deploying new PC's at the start of a rollout.  Machines are being setup for different groups one batch at a time.  I need a batch, command, or powershell to assign ownership for certain folders.
I have tried a few different batch-files but to no avail.
I use this:

```
takeown /f "c:\program files" /r /d y
```

it works fine.  Then I try this:

```
icacls "c:\program files" /setowner "LocalAdmin"
```

but nothing happens. I am not opposed to using any of the 3 (.bat, cmd, or ps). I just need something simple that works.  I figure this is the place to ask.  You guys have helped me so many times, by answering other questions for people.  I am forever grateful.

Comment: Set-Acl can be used to set the ownership on a file or folder.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on that?  I'm a bit of a novice...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the owner of a file using the `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` cmdlets.  For example, here's how to assign ownership to the local 'Administrators' group:

```
# Get the 'Administrators' identity
$adminGroup = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount('Administrators')

# Get the existing ACL for the file
$fileACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\TargetFile.txt"

# Set the new owner in the ACL - inmemory only
$fileACL.SetOwner($adminGroup)

# Write updated ACL back to file
Set-Acl -Path "C:\TargetFile.txt" -AclObject $fileACL
```