# How to set TrustedInstaller as owner of cmd.exe?

Tags: powershell, permissions, owner, system32, icacls

I currently have to change permissions for all local users on cmd.exe. 
So far I have taken the ownership of the file and changed the permissions in the way i need it.

My problem is, that I cant figure out, how to give the ownership back to TrustedIntstaller.

Below you can see the code I worked out so far. It changes the permissions and throws no errors, but after the script ran the owner is still set to System.

Iam using the Powershell App Deployment Toolkit and the script was executed as system-user.

Any help is appreciated. If there are other (better) ways of changing permissions in Windows-Folder please let me know as well.

```
        $acl_old = get-acl "$envSystem32Directory\cmd.exe"
        $owner_old = $acl_old.Owner

        Execute-Process -Path "takeown.exe" -Parameters "/f C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
        Execute-Process -Path "icacls.exe" -Parameters "$envSystem32Directory\cmd.exe /grant:r *S-1-2-0:(RX)"

        $new_permission = get-acl "$envSystem32Directory\cmd.exe"
        $new_owner_object = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList "$owner_old"
        $new_permission.SetOwner($new_owner_object)
        set-acl -Path $envSystem32Directory\cmd.exe -AclObject $new_permissions
```

Comment: I forgot that line in the code-snippet. But it already was in my script and it does not change anything. Set-acl -Path "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe -AclObject $new_permissions

Comment: See a previous answer of mine: [Is there ... powershell, that will assign ownership of a file ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727624/is-there-a-batch-file-command-line-or-powershell-that-will-assign-ownership-o/55730998#55730998). In your case, change the account name in my example to "NT Service\Trustedinstaller".  Note that you might need to be running elevated for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Mine and boxdogs code are working. But it wasnt complete. In order  to be able to restore TrustedInstaller als the owner some DLL and Privileges have to be loaded.

If anyone else is having this issue, here is a solution. After adding the DLL-Load and Privileges to my script it is working.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/87679d43-04d5-4894-b35b-f37a6f5558cb/solved-how-to-take-ownership-and-change-permissions-for-blocked-files-and-folders-in-powershell